# bind a label to a given encoding with sklearn LabelEncoder

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
l_labels = ['[PAD]'] + ['NN', 'ADJ', 'PRON'] 
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(l_labels)
le.trasform('[PAD]')

>>>> 3
```

I want the encodind of '[PAD]' to be 0. Is it possible to bind a label to an encoding with LabelEncoder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the scikit learn **LabelEncoder** is **sorting** the list of element before the transformation one way to encode 'PAD' to be 0 is the change the name of PAD to some thing that will be sorted as first.

```
l_labels = ['0' + 'PAD'] + ['NN', 'ADJ', 'PRON'] 
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(l_labels)
le.transform(['0'+'PAD'])
>> [0]
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that in `LabelEncoder` because it first finds the unique elements and then sorts them to assign numerical encoding.

#### what happens internally in the `fit` method.

```
uniques_set = set(values)
uniques_set, missing_values = _extract_missing(uniques_set)

uniques = sorted(uniques_set)
```

Ref: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913be6d7e485b792ea36e9268be31ed52d0/sklearn/utils/_encode.py#L135